# ¿Como recorrer un ciclo for en una función javascript que se ejecuta al cargar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, funciones, angular

tengo una función que se ejecuta apenas se carga la pagina, esta funcion lo que hace es asignarle valores a variables, los valores están en un array.

el problema que tengo es que la función no recorre el array porque encuentra el array vació, la única forma que funcione es que con un ng-click llame a la función, el problema es que necesito que las variables estén cargadas apenas se cargue la pagina.

```
$http.get("/indicadores").then(function(response){
    $scope.indicadores = response.data;
});

$scope.indicadores = [];


    $(document).ready(function(){
    var userID = document.getElementById("userID").value;
    console.log("usuario" +userID);
    $scope.tecnologia=0; 
    $scope.aprendizaje=0; 
    $scope.gestion=0;
    var numindicadores = $scope.indicadores.length;
    console.log("num de indicadores ff: "+numindicadores);
    var i=0;

    if($scope.tecnologia==0 && $scope.aprendizaje==0 && $scope.gestion==0){
        console.log("hola");
        for(i; i<numindicadores; i++){
            console.log("hola en indicadores");
            if($scope.indicadores[i].user_id == userID){
                if($scope.indicadores[i].dimension == 'Tecnología'){
                    $scope.tecnologia = $scope.indicadores[i].indicadorD;
                    console.log("hola tec");
                }else if($scope.indicadores[i].dimension == 'Aprendizaje'){
                    $scope.aprendizaje = $scope.indicadores[i].indicadorD;
                    console.log("hola apr");
                }else if($scope.indicadores[i].dimension == 'Gestión'){
                    $scope.gestion = $scope.indicadores[i].indicadorD;
                    console.log("hola ges");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("aprendizaje: " + $scope.aprendizaje, "Tecnologia: " + $scope.tecnologia, "Gestion: " + $scope.gestion);
})
```

estoy utilizando angular.
Gracias.

Comment: Podrias poner la respuesta de indicadores en un hidden input que este disponible al cargar la pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando Angular, podrías aprovecharte de sus bondades.

Para el ciclo que necesitas puedes implementar un foreach que recorra el arreglo donde tienes guardada la información, para así poder usarla de forma más simple:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $http.get("/indicadores").then(function(response){
     $scope.indicadores = response.data;

 var userID = document.getElementById("userID").value;
 console.log("usuario" +userID);
 $scope.tecnologia=0; 
 $scope.aprendizaje=0; 
 $scope.gestion=0;

 //var numindicadores = $scope.indicadores.length; Esto ya no lo necesitas, usas Angular! :)
 //console.log("num de indicadores ff: "+numindicadores);
 //var i=0;

 if($scope.tecnologia==0 && $scope.aprendizaje==0 && $scope.gestion==0){
    console.log("hola");
    $.each($scope.indicadores, function (index,value) {
         console.log("hola en indicadores");
          if(value.user_id == userID){
                if(value.dimension == 'Tecnología'){
                   $scope.tecnologia = value.indicadorD;
                   console.log("hola tec");
                }else if(value.dimension == 'Aprendizaje'){
                   $scope.aprendizaje = value.indicadorD;
                   console.log("hola apr");
                }else if(value.dimension == 'Gestión'){
                   $scope.gestion = value.indicadorD;
                   console.log("hola ges");
                }
          }
    });

console.log("aprendizaje: " + $scope.aprendizaje, "Tecnologia: " + 
$scope.tecnologia, "Gestion: " + $scope.gestion);

 });
})
```

Además claro, poniendo la llamada http dentro de la función onReady ayuda a que la página cargue primero, luego haga la llamada para traer la información. Luego el ciclo y el análisis de datos lo ponemos dentro de la función `then` del request para esperar a que la información este lista para usarse y así no recibas el arreglo vacío al momento de usar los datos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, fue de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Primero se carga la pagina y luego ejecuta el GET. Y por mas que lo ejecute antes, una request http es mas lenta que una carga. Entonces, tenes que esperar a que se cargue la pagina para realizar el GET y luego esperar a que se finalice el GET para ejecutar la funcion:

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Cargo la página
  // Código
  $http.get("/indicadores").then(function(response){
    $scope.indicadores = response.data;

    // Llamas a la funcion que necesitas.
    if($scope.tecnologia==0 && $scope.aprendizaje==0 && $scope.gestion==0){
      for(i; i<numindicadores; i++) {
        // Tu función
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, probé lo que me dices pero aun sigue como si el array estuviese vació.

Comment: Estoy viendo, que abajo del GET inicializas el array como vacio. Puede ser que tengas que inicializarlo primero y a continuación poner el GET?

Comment: nada, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Como esta tu codigo ahora? **(1)**: Inicializas como [], **(2)**: document.ready, **(3)**: GET, **(4)**: dentro del GET el for.
Correcto? (Uno dentro de otro, no? Solo la inicializacion fuera.)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió bastante para encontrar la solución.